# How to get Email from coming code for Reset Password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, reset-password

I am using ASP.NET MVC and implemented all the funtionality from Register to Login and Forgot Password and reset password as well.

Here in Reset Password there is a code define that is coming from email to check that coming code for Reset Password is null or not that is ok running fine but I want to get the Email for particular user that is trying to reset the password so user do not need to write his / her email again.

So where I have to check that code in Database and get that user's email so I can set it in view model and pass so it will display!

Reset Password:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
{
      return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
}
```

Here I want to get the Email of the user who is trying to reset the password.

Please someone suggest me how I can do this!

Comment: Your method is marked anonymous. An anonymous user may not even have a email. What is this method actually doing and where is it called from?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have declared it as AllowAnonymous because the user who is coming to reset the password is no longer logged in so user can't access that feature unless we give permission as AllowAnonymous. Any way thanks for replay I got a solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly - so the user must provide their email or something to identify them

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am daily seeing you posts and answers in SO.. You are rocking Asp.net in SO..

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't remove AllowAnonymous because if I remove that it will redirect user to login page and that is totally wrong so if user pass email still that function will not allow to go without login unless we provide it as AllowAnonymous because I have **authorize** my controller so it is compulsary for me to set it as **AllowAnonymous**.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you do - just pointing out that you need to pass something identifying the user - but I see you worked it out :)

Comment: But the code you have shown suggests you may not be implementing this correctly - [this article](https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/) might be useful

Comment: @StephenMuecke No no sir there is no any intention form me to point out you as you are suggesting me or anything but I am telling you the procedure that I have to follow as per my knowledge and belief sir. Thank you so much sir for such amazing response and for the link you have provided as well.

Answer (score 1):

Oops I made a mistake to getting missing parameter.

I just have to get the userId and than my problem is solved.

Here is a Code as I have implemented:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string userId ,string code)
        {
            if (code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            else {
                ResetPasswordViewModel model = new ResetPasswordViewModel();
                model.Email = UserManager.GetEmail(userId);
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

So in my viewmodel I have set my email so it will automatically display stored information in View.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify text box's name as "code" in your view.

If you use plain HTML then use below.

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="yourclass" />
```

HTML Helper then use below.

```
@Html.TextBox("code", new {@class="yourclass" })
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong dear! My question is to get the email to display by using code i.e. check from database and get email and display, not code.

Comment: @padhiyar ok u have do your BL.  Ohhh you got answer.. Cheers